What are common drag and lift coefficients of aircrafts using frontal area as reference plane?
What are common drag and lift coefficients of aircrafts using frontal area as reference plane?
I want to know this numbers to see how actually streamlined are  planes compared with other objects, cars, etc..
I will write one example:
glider wing 20m2, frontal area 1,2-2.0m2
using wing area
Cd- 0,02-0,04
Cl - 1.0-1.5
using frontal area
scale by wing/frontal factor x12
Cd- 0,24-0,48
CL- 12-18
Cd of 0.48 is very bad result for object, so this numbers are missleading (even if we use same reference surface) when we compare object that produce lift(glider) with object that not produce lift (any shape). Because glider looks more streamlined than some boxy shape.

You just have to scale the coefficients by a factor $\frac{S_{frontal}}{S_{wing}}$

@sophit how do you mean? If wing area is 12x bigger then frontal area, that mean Cd and Cl will be 12x bigger when use frontal area as reference surface.

@sophit glider is 0.48, that is very bad for car...so this numbers are misleading when we compare object that produce lift with object that not produce lift...induced drag...

@sophit I think aerodynamics efficiency L/D is not missleading, even we use different reference surface..

Yes, L/D doesn't change and yes, if you compare the drag of a flying object with a rolling one the comparison is unfair (due to the induced drag)... But comparing the $C_{d_0}$ of an airplane with the $C_x$ of a car can be done

One can back calculate Cd of an aircraft from it's glide ratio, which corresponds to sine glide angle × weight = "thrust" (graviational component).  Thrust = Drag.  Most of the drag comes from the fuselage.


What are common drag and lift coefficients of aircraft using the frontal area as a reference? I want to know these numbers to see how actually streamlined are planes compared with other objects, cars, etc..

The comparison you want to do among automotive and aeronautical vehicles can be done but it is fair only considering a not-flying aircraft in order to avoid the induced drag which is something not existing in the automotive world.
Then we take only the parasite drag into consideration. This drag is anyway not proportional to the wing surface nor to the frontal area of the object rather to its wetted surface i.e. the surface directly in contact with the air: So if we really want to make a comparison among different bodies we should actually consider their wetted surface. This information on the wetted area is normally missing but it's not a problem since we can simply use a different kind of drag.
Like any aerodynamic force, drag is defined as:
$D=½ \rho V^2 S C_d$
Now, if the two vehicles are moving in the same air density $\rho$ and at the same speed $V$ then the only difference in drag $D$ comes from the product $SC_d$ which is termed "equivalent flat-plate drag" and is measured in m².
For example, according to Wikipedia a SUV can have a $C_x \times A$ as high as 1.6m²  while a Cessna C172 with a wing surface of 16.2m² and a plausible $C_{d_0}$ of 0.02 has a relevant value of 0.324m²: At the same density and speed, the Cessna needs a thrust 5 times smaller than a modern SUV.

race cars produce downforce, this car produce 17 000N downforce at 160km/h, has L/D 16:1   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLIEeDL2J6M
